# Replicate the TFLite model layers using python function of conv2d etc

Tags: tensorflow, convolution, resnet, activation

If I want to replicate the layers in a TFLite model using python tensorflow functions for performing a few experiments on the tensor data, how do I do that?
conv can be done by tf.nn.conv2d, but adding bias to it and then applying relu is not giving correct output.
Which all functions would work - Model - tf resnet50 converted to tflite using tensorflow lite converter and optimizations command

Comment: I can't understand the question. It would be very helpful if you provided the code you've tried so far and what hasn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

I went through this a few months ago. The problem with trying to replicate TFLite layers in regular Tensorflow is that the ordering for weights is different. Example for conv2d:

- TFLite - [out_channels, filter_height, filter_width, in_channels]
- Regular TF - [filter_height, filter_width, in_channels, out_channels]

Here is an example python implementation that takes in a TFLite tensor W and reorders it such that it can be used in regular TF:

```
def reorderWeights(W, in_channels, out_channels, kernel):
     flatW = W.flatten()
     newW = []
     for j in range(in_channels*kernel*kernel):
          for i in range(out_channels):
              newW.append(flatW[i*(kernel*kernel*in_channels) + j])
     newW = np.array(newW)
     return newW.reshape(kernel, kernel, in_channels, out_channels)
```